# Model validation, database constraints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, cqrs

I'm trying to add some architecture to my projects and enrich my models.
I started with CQS (implementation similar to that one: [CQS-Sample](https://github.com/Code-First/CQS-Sample)) and here's my first problem.

Let's say I have two classes like these below:

```
public class Network
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    private IQueryFactory _queryFactory { get; set; }

    public Network(IQueryFactory queryFactory)
    {
        _queryFactory = queryFactory;
    }

    public void AddUser(User user)
    {
        if(this.User == null && user != null)
        {
            userHasUniqueEmail(user);
            this.User = user;
        }

    }

    private void userHasUniqueEmail(User user)
    {
        bool isUnique = _queryFactory.ResolveQuery<INewUserUniqueQuery>().Execute(user.Email);
        if (!isUnique)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("E-mail is not unique");
        }
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Network object can have User, but I need to check first in database that given e-mail doesn't already exists or do some other checkings, so my commands will be executed successfully.
By adding user I mean adding completely new User to database.
Would it be correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the way you do it now and it's ok.

Another option is to make this Validation in `Contoller`. Then you should use [Remote attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx). And Move your `IsEmailUnique(string mail)` method to `Controller`.

If you want to know how you can do it with email check - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582810/mvc-remote-validation-unique-email-address) will help you.